# XDocument.Save() add unwanted namespace on each XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, ttml

I have the following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" 
    xmlns:tt="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml"     
    xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling"
    xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xml:lang="fr-FR"
    ttp:timeBase="smpte" ttp:frameRate="24" ttp:frameRateMultiplier="999 1000" ttp:dropMode="nonDrop">
  <head>
    <styling>
      <style xml:id="normal" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
      <style xml:id="bold" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="bold" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
      <style xml:id="italic" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="italic" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
      <style xml:id="bolditalic" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="bold" tts:fontStyle="italic" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
    </styling>
```

When I load it with `XDocument.Load()` then save it with `XDocument.Save()` without any changes, the new XML file I have is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tt:tt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tt="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml"
       xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling"
       xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter"
       xml:lang="fr-FR" ttp:timeBase="smpte"     ttp:frameRate="24" ttp:frameRateMultiplier="999 1000" ttp:dropMode="nonDrop">
  <tt:head>
    <tt:styling>
      <tt:style xml:id="normal" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="normal"     tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%" />
      <tt:style xml:id="bold" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="bold"     tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%" />
      <tt:style xml:id="italic" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="normal"     tts:fontStyle="italic" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%" />
      <tt:style xml:id="bolditalic" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="bold"     tts:fontStyle="italic" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%" />
    </tt:styling>
```

Is there an elegant way to load and save this kind of XML without changing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" and xmlns:tt="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml"? The default namespace (xmlns) should be enough, no need for xmlns:tt I think

Comment: This is a good question, I just need to re-create a file which is like that..

Answer (score 5):

As Pascal said, the problem comes from  `xmlns="w3.org/ns/ttml"` and `xmlns:tt="w3.org/ns/ttml"`. I think `XDocument.Save` generate this xml because the default xml namespace  is duplicated with another namespace. (Namespaces are maybe more identified by valeu than by key ?)

First Option is to remove the duplicate in your input file.
Using this new version, you won't have any problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml"    
    xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling"
    xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xml:lang="fr-FR"
    ttp:timeBase="smpte" ttp:frameRate="24" ttp:frameRateMultiplier="999 1000" ttp:dropMode="nonDrop">
  <head>
    <styling>
      <style xml:id="normal" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
      <style xml:id="bold" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="bold" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
      <style xml:id="italic" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="italic" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
      <style xml:id="bolditalic" tts:fontFamily="sansSerif" tts:fontWeight="bold" tts:fontStyle="italic" tts:color="white" tts:fontSize="100%"/>
    </styling>
```

Second option is to remove the duplicate namespace somewhere before the save

```
doc.Root.Attributes(XName.Get("tt", @"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")).Remove();
```